# Disable PXE progamatically in parallels?

Tags: mac, parallels

I'm running Parallels 4.0 on Mac OS X 10.5.8.

I'm trying to create a bunch of Virtual Machines from the commandline, using the [prlctl](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Command_Line_Reference_Guide/) tool, like so:

```
$ prlctl create test1 -o linux -d centos
$ prlctl set test1 --device-del cdrom0
$ prlctl start test1
```

Now, each time I start a new VM, the VM spends time waiting for a PXE boot. I'd like to turn this off.

Can I disable PXE requests using Parallels or a Parallels commandline tool?

Or, can I set the boot order of a VM from the commandline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

The Boot Order is determined by the order in which you create the devices. So, the following example will boot with the CDROM first, then the Network card. PXE is therefore never used:

```
$ prlctl set test1 --device-del cdrom0
Remove the cdrom0 device.
The VM has been successfully configured.
$ prlctl set test1 --device-add cdrom --enable --image /Users/stefanl/Downloads/Mirrors/CentOS/CentOS-5.5-x86_64-netinstall.iso
Creating cdrom0 (+) ide:1 image='~/Downloads/Mirrors/CentOS/CentOS-5.5-x86_64-netinstall.iso'
The VM has been successfully configured.
$ prlctl set test1 --device-del net0
Remove the net0 device.
The VM has been successfully configured.
$ prlctl set test1 --device-add net --enable
Creating net0 (+) type=shared mac=001C42F15907
The VM has been successfully configured.
```

My boot order is now:

1. Floppy
2. CDROM
3. Network card
4. HDD